# Random terrain generation

Tags: java

How can I make a terrain generator that makes more realistic terrain? 
My current generator makes this type of terrain:

[image]

how can I make it make more real terrain, like lakes and rivers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you define and apply a set of filters on your generated terrain.

I can't go into full detail but I'll provide some hints for you to google:

1. voronoi diagrams
2. erosion filters
3. perturbation
4. ...

For rivers you could create a voronoi diagram that has thin dark lines between the light cells. You could have some gradient from dark to light for smooth transitions. Then you mulitply that diagram with your generated terrain effectively lowering hight along those lines. Together with the irregular shape of your terrain you could get some non-straight "proto"-rivers.

Next you could apply an erosion filter that simulates rain, water flow and erosion to get more realistic and smooth rivers and lakes.

This should get you started.

For more information pay [VTerrain.org](http://vterrain.org/) a visit, for example this page: http://vterrain.org/Elevation/Artificial/, or this for water simulation (hydrogeology): http://vterrain.org/Water/index.html#Hydrogeology

Answer (score 1):

While it's not in Java, Freeciv has a fairly tunable random-terrain-grid generation core that you might like to read over.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeciv/ has the sources; I don't see a public repository for it, on a casual search.

Alternatively, you might look into using a  [genetic algorithm for terrain generation](http://google.com/?q=terrain-generation%20genetic-algorithm), as these tend to produce very nice pseudo-realistic results.

Answer (score 1):

A nice and simple way to generate a heightmap is the [Diamond-Square algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm). See this article on [Generating Random Fractal Terrain](http://gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html) for a complete tutorial and pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly used fractal terrain-generating techniques subdivide squares or triangles, but Robert Krten described an interesting alternative in his article, "Generating Realistic Terrain", published in the Jul-1994 issue of "Dr. Dobb's Journal":

http://drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/184409269

In short, the terrain begins as a completely flat height map.  Successively smaller faults are applied, in which all elements on one side of a random line are made higher.  A smoothing process simulates erosion at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For me, terrain generation is a multi-step process.

( 1 ) Start out with primitive shapes like domes, which can be generated the same way every time.  Alternatively, You can also experiment with Voronoi plates and have levels rise where collisions happen.  Also look into Perlin Noise.

( 2a ) Simulate erosion using rainfall.  Fluvial erosion can be simulated with spheres "rolling" down the slopes of your terrain.  As a drop flows over a node, it takes a small chunk of land with it, reducing the height of the land.

Where the droplets go next is determined by the lowest negative change in elevation amongst your neighboring nodes or tiles.  After each erosion round, or even drop, you can smooth the terrain so future drops will know where to drop.

As your drops roll down slopes, they will eventually need to find a stopping point.  The most realistic and time-consuming method would be to find water flooding levels to make lakes and oceans.  A faster method is to have the drops reduce in size over time and stop when they reach zero.

( 2b ) Generate a water flow map for erosion.  This is good for river generation.  The basic idea is to find an edge point for flow-off.  You can have multiple flow-off points, but you will have to process the river generation algorithm in parallel.  The basic idea for the algorithm is

```
start out by making directed graph(s) for water flow:
    push the edge points onto a stack as seeds;
    while stack is not empty:
        pop a node;
        mark node as visited;
        randomly select a number of backflow forks (1 to 3 usually works);
        select up to that number of unvisited nodes, depending on which are unvisited;
        // this can be done randomly or based on the height of primitive terrain;
        make links from popped node to selected fork nodes;
        push the selected fork nodes;

now simulate flow volume:
    initialize a flow-volume value for each node or tile to be zero;
    for each tile on the map:
        push tile on to a stack;
        while the node stack is not empty:
            pop a node;
            increment the node's flow volume by 1;
            push any backflow neighbors;
```

You can use the water volume map to decide an amount to erode (depth and radius of dirt dig).  Alternatively, you could use it to pre-script drop flow 2a's algorithm. You would have to change the direction of the directed graph arcs though.

( 3 ) After Erosion, you can apply light noise to the terrain for rockiness. I find additive blends of random circle radii to be a useful and fast method.  You could also use Perlin noise with higher octaves than what you used for your base terrain.  Just remember blurs will soften your slopes and noise will make things sharper.

This will give you a somewhat decent terrain.  If you want to go further, you could look into lake generation and cliff generation.  You would also have to decide if you want other features like craters, arches, mesas, and towers.

Fractal coastlines and rivers are also worth looking into.  I would just get all of Mandelbrot's books and papers on the subject.  There is a wealth of info on terrain generation from him, even though his work can be applied to a much greater scope of computer science, and mathematics.